# Segmentation Fault in Merge Sort in C

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, segmentation-fault, mergesort

I recently tried to implement the merge sort algorithm. I understood the basic concept behind it and even took a peek at one of it's C implementations online but when I try to do it on my own, I always seem to get a segmentation fault.
I am also confused if to use mid or mid+1 in places.

Please help me fix this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int merge(int arr[], int low, int mid, int high);
int mergeSort(int arr[], int low, int high);
int main(void)
{
    int sample[5]={66,7,11,2,99}; //Sample array for sorting.
    mergeSort(sample, 0, 4); //Calling the function
    
}
int merge(int arr[], int low, int mid, int high)
{
    if(high>low) //Merge will only work when high is greater than low and mid.
    {
        int leftSide[mid]; // Dividing the array into two parts, this is the left side; low to mid.
        int rightSide[(high-mid)];  //This is the right side; mid to high.
        for(int i=0;i<=mid;i++)
        {
            leftSide[i]=arr[i]; //Filling the leftSide array.
        }
        for (int x=mid; x<=high; x++)
        {
            rightSide[x]=arr[x]; //Filling the rightSide array.
        }
        for(int m,l,r=0; m<=high; m++)
        {
            if(leftSide[l]>rightSide[r])
            {
                arr[m]=rightSide[r]; //If the element on rightSide is lesser than on the leftSide then it will come first in the final array.
                r++; //Increment the counter so next comparision can begin.
            }
            else if(leftSide[l]<rightSide[r])
            {
                arr[m]=leftSide[l]; //If the element on leftSide is lesser than on the rightSide then it will come first in the final array
                l++; //Increment the counter so next comparision can begin.
            }
            else //This will be the case if the numbers are equal
            {
                if(l<mid) //If the left Index has not reached its maximum limit 
                {
                    arr[m]=leftSide[l]; 
                    l++;
                }
                else if(r<(high-mid)) // If the right Index has not reached its maximum limit
                {
                    arr[m]=rightSide[r];
                    r++;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

int mergeSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if(high>low)
    {
        int mid=round((high+low)/2);
        mergeSort(arr, low, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid, high);
        merge(arr, low, mid, high);

    }
    else //Base Case
    {
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<=high;i++) //Printing the array.
    {
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Well, for one, `mergeSort(arr, low, high);` in the recursion call makes no sense. The point of the recursion is to partition the data into two segments  by low, mid, and high: the (low,mid) segment, and the (mid,high) segment). The line immediately preceding recursed to `low, mid`, the high partition should be done with `mid,high`, not `low,high` That said, I prefer base + length schemas instead, as you're far less apt to have segments of length-1 causing poor implementations to spiral.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake, I changd  `mergeSort(arr,low,high);` to
`mergeSort(arr,mid,high);`
It is still returning a seg fault

Comment: In `for(int m,l,r=0; m<=high; m++)` the variables `m` and `l` are uninitialized. You only set r to 0.  This means you will potentially index into `arr[]` and `leftside[]` with illegal indices, causing a segfault.

Comment: Hey I declared l and r separately, but its still showing a segfault :( .

Comment: For the love of.... *run your program in a **debugger***. The fault will include a call stack, and the ability to evaluate variables to see what is breaching your arrays (and with a simple native mergesort, it will *always* be either an array breach or a stack overflow; one of the two). Regarding a simpler merge sort [this](https://godbolt.org/z/fG9dzWMn3) was what i was referring to earlier.

Comment: Don't think you need to be rather annoyed here but anyways thanks for the advice.
I will also check the code you provided, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault occur when you access unallocated memory.
In mergeSort function, you called merge function by passing indexes to call merge function.

```
    if(high>low)
    {
        int mid=round((high+low)/2);
        mergeSort(arr, low, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid, high);
        merge(arr, low, mid, high);

    }
```

Inside merge function when you declared leftSide and rightSide arrays, The size of arrays should be index + 1, As array index starts from 0.

```
        int leftSide[mid + 1]; // Dividing the array into two parts, this is the left side; low to mid.
        int rightSide[(high-mid) + 1];  //This is the right side; mid to high.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, I tried it out, but nothing has changed so far, it is still showing segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

In `for(int m,l,r=0; m<=high; m++)` the variables `m` and `l` are uninitialized. You only set r to 0.  This means you will potentially index into `arr[]` and `leftSide[]` with illegal indices, causing a segfault.

The variables m, l, r are so called [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable), and these are default uninitialized.

Also, when you split `arr[]` between `leftSide[]` and `rightSide[]`, you are placing the `arr[mid]` value into both arrays.

Comment: Hey I declared l and r separately, but its still showing a segfault :( .
Thanks for the info at the bottom, it helped me understand mergesort a little bit more.

Comment: @AouxWoux and `m`?

Comment: What is the need to declare m itself? I defined it normally in the for loop:
'for(int m=0; m<=high;m++)'

Comment: Yes, that should be good.

Comment: Still not working :(